# How to change color for certain points in a plot that has been saved with an object in R?

Tags: r, plot, colors, r-markdown, igraph

everybody!

I'm working on an RMarkdown file. I plot something in previous chunks and save the plot in an object, say ***'img'***, because I want to do stuff to that plot in subsequent chunks. How can I change the color of certain points in ***'img'*** without changing anything else? Or can I at least add some new points in that color to overlay certain points?

Some codes I found online look like the following, but it doesn't work for me. Keeps saying that *"plot.new has not been called yet"*. And as a beginner in R, I'm afraid I don't understand why ***plot.new( )*** is relevant in this case.

```
   img
   points(x,y, col="black", psh=15, cex=2)
   img <- recordPlot()
```

Plus, I'm not sure this is the right way to modify a plot in different chunks. If there's a better way, please let me know! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `points()` if you haven't set up the plot window, which is what `plot.new()` would do.  Normally you don't call `plot.new()` directly, some other function (e.g. `plot()`) calls it before doing other things.

So this way of drawing this should work to add some points:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
plot(x, y, col = "red")   # implicit call to plot.new()
img <- recordPlot()

dev.off()                 # clears the display; not needed in RMarkdown
img                       # redraws the first plot
points(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = "green") # adds green points
```

Changing the colour of points may not work perfectly, because antialiasing means the old colour can leak through.  But this sequence should do it to change the original points to green:

```
img
points(x, y, col = "green")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be editing a bunch of plots, you may want to consider using `ggplot2` as your graphing library rather than base. There are many, many online resources to help you get started there. Here is just a quick example:

```
library(ggplot2)

img <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg))

img
```

[image: original ggplot2 picture]

Now suppose you want to color some of the points. This vector will make all of the points `lightblue`, and then set the first 5 back to `black`.

```
point_colors <- rep("lightblue", nrow(mtcars))
point_colors[1:5] <- "black"
```

We can layer this directly back on top of the plot:

```
img <- img +
  geom_point(aes(x = hp, y = mpg), color = point_colors)

img
```

[image: colored picture]

With `ggplot2`, we can see how the plot is layered by running `img$layers` which gives:

```
> img$layers
[[1]]
mapping: x = ~hp, y = ~mpg 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity 

[[2]]
mapping: x = ~hp, y = ~mpg 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

We can remove a layer by setting it to null:

```
img$layers[[1]] <- NULL

> img$layers
[[1]]
mapping: x = ~hp, y = ~mpg 
geom_point: na.rm = FALSE
stat_identity: na.rm = FALSE
position_identity
```

So now we removed the original layer and are just left with the one with changed colors. With ggplot2, it is fairly easy to change things later (especially just clean additions).

```
img +
  ggtitle("only one layer!") +
  theme_light()
```

[image: modified ggplot image]

Comment: Hey, Adam. That sounds like a fantasic idea! Thank a lot! Although I tried and error occurred again, saying that "non-numeric argument to binary operator". I don't understand that either. Could it be because that `img` was a random graph plotted with `igraph` rather than `ggplot2`?

Comment: Yeah that's likely. Need to operate under a single graphing paradigm usually!

Comment: I see. I'll try something else. Thank you very much! @Adam